# Inserting values for datetime column giving error

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have a `datetime` column whose value I am adding as below

```
xw.WriteElementString("EXPIREDATE", Convert.ToDateTime(txtEndDate.Text.ToString()));
```

But it is giving error as

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteElementString(string, string)' has some invalid arguments

how to resolve it

**UPDATE**

Whenever I dont add date in the textbox it works but when I add the date in `dd/MM/yyyy` format it doesnt works. how to make it work

**Code**

```
xw.WriteElementString("EXPIREDATE", txtEndDate.Text.ToString().Trim());

            if (txtEndDate.Text != "")
            {
                DateTime enddate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtEndDate.Text.ToString());
                DateTime sysdate = Convert.ToDateTime(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));

                if (sysdate < enddate)
                {
                    xw.WriteElementString("DELETE_FLAG", "N");
                }
                else
                {
                    xw.WriteElementString("DELETE_FLAG", "Y");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                xw.WriteElementString("DELETE_FLAG", "N");
            }
```

Comment: What's the format of date inside txtEndDate.Text?

Comment: its `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

Comment: Please refer to DateTime.TryParseExact or ParseExact methods. You'll be able to pass specific format

Comment: Don't be lazy, you can find it on on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are passing a DateTime when the method expects a string.  You want something like this instead:

```
xw.WriteElementString("EXPIREDATE", DateTime.Parse(txtEndDate.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Also notice that `Convert.ToDateTime` will return `DateTime.Min` if the given string is not in a correct format, while `DateTime.Parse` will throw an exception. You should instead use `DateTime.TryParse`

Comment: It will raise an exception if provided text isn't in a CurrentCulture format.

Comment: since this is input from user, I wouldn't recommend anyone to use DateTime.Parse or Convert.ToDateTime methods :)

Comment: When I add date in `dd/MM/yyyy` format it doesnt works but when i dont add date it works.. WHY

Comment: @nad Please edit your question and add how it works and how it doesn't

Comment: @nad can you post the exact code you are using? I suspect you are calling .ToString before closing the parenthesis

Comment: I have updated with code @CamiloTerevinto. have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134384/discussion-between-camilo-terevinto-and-nad).

Answer (score 3):

As error says clearly,  `WriteElementString` method takes 2 `string` value

```
xw.WriteElementString("EXPIREDATE", Convert.ToDateTime(txtEndDate.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

**NOTE:**

Use `DateTime.TryParse` to control if `txtEndDate.Text` is valid `datetime`, and then use `value`

Comment: Please provide a comment to your answer, code-only answers are discouraged

Comment: what if I want to give this as `dd/MM/yyyy` format ?

Answer (score 0):

As it mentions you need to pass both argument in `string` format, in your case your first argument is right, but the next argument is in `datetime`. So please try doing this to convert it to the `string`

```
xw.WriteElementString("EXPIREDATE", Convert.ToDateTime(txtEndDate.Text).ToString());
```